# Prism Version 7.x for UWP

Tags: uwp, prism

I'm looking for the Prism Version 7.x for a UWP app. I see only the Xamarin.Forms and the WPF version.

I've used the Version 6.3 for UWP. Now I'd like to have a common library with my Xamarin.Forms app and my UWP app. This is a Problem, because of the differeces in the old Version 6.3 and the Version 7.2 of Prism. (I don't use Xamarin.Forms for UWP but pure UWP).

Comment: This is not a generic forum, but a code-problem-solving one.

Comment: This is definitely a very valid question, see my answer for explanation. The dropping of UWP support was too prominently highlighted among the changes in 7.x, so I can see why the OP is surprised

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Prism maintainers decided to drop support for non-Xamarin.Forms UWP projects at the time being because of the maintenance costs involved. There is a possibility that the support will return in the future with growing popularity of UWP and Uno Platform, but at the moment, you will have to look into alternatives like [MvvmCross](http://mvvmcross.com/) or [Mvvm Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). Both are great frameworks.

Alternatively, as I can see you like to use pure UWP instead of Xamarin.Forms, you might be interested in trying the [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/), which provides UWP XAML and API on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I used MvvmCross and Mvvm Light in the past and therefore I've used Prism afterwards. Prism is a much better option for my Projects. I'll try to find an alternative framemork or just to use only a part of Prism as source from Github.

Comment: The Uno Plattform is really great!

Comment: I understand, I have transitioned my project to Prism as well only to find it deprecated shortly afterwards. But I still hope it will come back one day!